# identify which ingress / service requested the pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

we have two ingress controllers and two separate services like below requesting the same deployment (pod). below are the service definitions.

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-1
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
  type: NodePort
```

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-2
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
  type: NodePort
```

Ingress definitions are below

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=150
    namespace: staging
spec:
  rules:
    - host: domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: service-1
              servicePort: 80
              
              
              
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-2
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=150
    namespace: staging
spec:
  rules:
    - host: different_domain_name.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: service-2
              servicePort: 80
```

when a request comes to the pod, is there a way i can identify which service / ingress received and processed the request.

ideally can i set some env variables at service or ingress level which i can access in the Pod?

Any help on how to achieve this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: you should be able to set a custom http header from your ingress controller

Comment: thanks for your reply, someone could easily spoof request headers, is it not possible to set env variables in service / ingress which can be accessed by pod?

Comment: if the request is passing through your ingress controller, you can easily prevent spoofing. Setting some environment variables wont do anything. The ingress controller and your app communicate through http, and thats the end of the story. You need to use http in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add env vars to Service or Ingress level. Service is just a logical set or binding of pods to send traffic to, you cannot add anything there. For Ingress, you can add headers

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  more_set_headers "Header: Value";
```